# How to use a variable in a function that can't be clobbered by variable name collision?

Tags: function-construction, variable-definitions

Not really sure what the right question to ask is.  But here's what I'm having trouble with:

```
ClearAll[Evaluate[Context[] <> "*"]]
klDivergence[d1_, d2_] := NExpectation[Log[ PDF[d1, x]/PDF[d2, x] ], x \[Distributed] d1]
d1 = NormalDistribution[0, 1];
d2 = NormalDistribution[5, 1]; 
klDivergence[d1, d2]
x=0
klDivergence[d1, d2]
```

The first call to klDivergence works fine.  The second one gives me an error or warning "NIntegrate::itraw: Raw object 0 cannot be used as an iterator."

What's the right way to code this, so that I can have a variable of integration inside my function that is not affected by external code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Localize `x` in a `Module`:

```
klDivergence[d1_, d2_] := Module[{x}, 
  NExpectation[Log[PDF[d1, x]/PDF[d2, x]], x \[Distributed] d1]]
```

Comment: A minor oversight in the language is that `With[{x}, ...]` is not allowed. It would be nice to be able to **immutably** localize a free variable, thus also protecting it from clobberage inside the function.

Comment: One could also use `\[FormalX]` as in `klDivergence[d1_, d2_] := 
 NExpectation[
  Log[PDF[d1, \[FormalX]]/
    PDF[d2, \[FormalX]]], \[FormalX] \[Distributed] d1]`. It cannot be overwritten because it is `Protected`. Comes close to `With[{x}, ...]`, doesn't it?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher It can be overwritten with `Block[{\[FormalX] = 1},...]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Oha, you're right! Okay, a further reason not to use it. =D

Answer (score 2):

John Doty's `Module` method is used a lot.  Alternatively, some internal functions use `K[n]`, where `n` is an integer chosen to make `K[n]` unique, especially for the dummy variable of integration or summation.  Something like the following effectively carries this out:

```
klDivergence[d1_, d2_] := 
  With[{serno = Max@{0, Cases[{d1, d2}, K[n_Integer] :> n, Infinity]} + 1},
   NExpectation[Log[PDF[d1, K[serno]]/PDF[d2, K[serno]]],
    K[serno] \[Distributed] d1]
   ];
```

However `K` is not [`Protected`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Protected.html), so the usage is not foolproof.  A user can assign a definition to `K` and mess the function up; it would also mess up internal functions that use `K`.  So if what's good enough for Wolfram is good enough for you, you have a solution.

A little safer would be to [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html) `K`.

```
klDivergence[d1_, d2_] := Block[{K},
   With[{serno = Max@{0, Cases[{d1, d2}, K[n_Integer] :> n, Infinity]} + 1},
    NExpectation[Log[PDF[d1, K[serno]]/PDF[d2, K[serno]]], 
     K[serno] \[Distributed] d1]
    ]];
```

This would block any user definition of `K` while `NExpectation` is being computed.  That's probably okay in this use-case, as well as most use cases; however, to block a user's definition from working does seem like a hole for a potential bug to creep through.  Of course a user should not be assigning values to `K`; that explicit advice is kept from users (i.e., it is not found in the documentation, at least not easily), but it is implied by the advice, ["you should always choose names for your own variables that start with lowercase letters."](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningVariables.html)

Another method used sometimes is to create one's own, perhaps `` Private` ``, context; for example, `` foo`x `` or `` foo`Private`x ``:

```
klDivergence[d1_, d2_] := Block[{foo`x},
   NExpectation[Log[PDF[d1, foo`x]/PDF[d2, foo`x]], 
    foo`x \[Distributed] d1]
   ];
```